# Fedora - iptables rules change after reboot, iptables-save do nothing

Tags: iptables

So I'm setting a new fedora install on my raspberrypi (version: newest pidora).

Everything works, except vnc, any connection attempts are rejected.

So, as I'd like to make it working now and worry about security later, I clear iptables with

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

Hacky, I know, but it makes VNC working.

Then, no matter whether I do

```
/sbin/service iptables save
```

or

```
iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

previous, non-permissive rules are restored, and thus, I can't get VNC to connect.

So, what gives? What's the problem?

For further reference, here are both iptables:

The 'unclean' one, the one that gets restored, and one which I don't want:

```
http://pastebin.com/UA3FKh9v
```

and the 'clean' one, the one that appears in iptables config file after iptables save, and the one that gets deleted after each reboot:

```
http://pastebin.com/Mj79YQ7g
```

Answer (score 2):

The newer Fedora versions (after 18) use firewalld as a default solution instead of iptables.
So all the configuration files are in `/etc/firewalld`

You can read extensively about firewalld configuration options [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD) .

Since you effectively want to stop the firewall service just do `systemctl stop firewalld.service` or to make it permanent `systemctl disable firewalld.service`

Comment: Ew.  Did not know that.  Seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @dmourati : If you mean disabling firewalld is a bad idea, not necessarily.  It isn't intended to be *more secure* than iptables, it is just more "feature rich".

Comment: @dmourati well that is what he was describing that he was doing if you check the actual pastbin files he posted. and yes depending on your particulars running without a firewall can be problematic